# How to exit an app in iphone 

Tags: iphone

Now i have to click the Home button twice and press one app until the close button appear, so many steps. Is there any quick way to exit currently opened app?

Comment: Do you mean a list of all applications installed?  The wording confuses me.

Comment: yes, I mean a list of all applications installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with the current SDK.